# convert headerless flat binary files to tif

Tags: wgs84, envi

I have set of headerless flat binary files (those are out put files of TIMESAT software). I want to convert those to .tif format.
I did it using ENVI. but it does not overlap with the original input files of TIMESAT(but both input and out put files are shows the coordinate system and datum as WGs84.). in the processing of TIMESAT no coortination transformation is occured.
can any one tel me what is the problem of ENVI.
or do you know some method to convert headerles flat binary to tif.